# How to find a sentence wrapped in asterisks in order to bold the text in my markup?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have a component for rendering text in posts/comments which uses regex for detecting mentions/hashtags/URLs. I want to find the pattern of text wrapped in pairs of asterisks in order to bold the text (similar to Markdown).

However, as you can see I am splitting text first by line and then by spaces because a mention, hashtag or URL is a word and I can simply get them by splitting on spaces. Making a sentence bold is different.

```
import {
  Theme,
  createStyles,
  WithStyles,
  withStyles,
  Link as MUI_Link,
} from "../components/material";
import { split_on_new_line } from "../utils";
import Link from "next/link";
import { RouterProps } from "next/router";
import { Send_to_root_T } from "../pages/_app";
import { get_a_user_info_by_username$$ } from "../utils/api";

const styles = function(theme: Theme) {
  return createStyles({
    wrapper: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing.unit,
      marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
      marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
      display: "block",
    },
    line: {
      display: "inline-block",
      width: "100%",
    },
  });
};

export interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  content: string;
  router: RouterProps;
  send_to_root: Send_to_root_T;
  link_class?: string;
  regular_text_class?: string;
}

function ContentProcessedText(props: Props) {
  const c = props.classes;
  const content = props.content;

  return (
    <span className={c.wrapper}>
      {split_on_new_line(content).map(function(chunk, i) {
        return (
          <span key={i} className={c.line}>
            {chunk.split(" ").map(function(item, i) {
              // Persian unicode special characters also included (specially ZWNJ)
              const hashtag_regex = /#[^\s!@#$%^&*()=+./,\[{\]};:'"?><،؛؟‌]+/gi;
              const url_regex = /[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/gi;
              const mention_regex = /@[0-9a-zA-Z_](\.?[0-9a-zA-Z-_])*/gi;
              const bold_regex = /\*\*(.+)\*\*/g;

              if (mention_regex.exec(item)) {
                const username = item.slice(1);
                return (
                  <span key={i}>
                    <MUI_Link
                      style={{
                        cursor: "pointer",
                      }}
                      className={props.link_class}
                      onClick={function(evt: React.MouseEvent) {
                        evt.stopPropagation();
                        props.send_to_root("SHOW_PROGRESS");
                        get_a_user_info_by_username$$(username).subscribe({
                          next: function(result) {
                            const uuid = result.data.uuid;

                            props.router.push(
                              {
                                pathname: `/profile`,
                                query: { user_id: uuid },
                              },
                              `/profile/${uuid}`,
                            );
                          },
                        });
                      }}
                    >
                      {`@${username}`}
                    </MUI_Link>{" "}
                  </span>
                );
              }

              if (url_regex.exec(item)) {
                return (
                  <span key={i}>
                    <MUI_Link
                      className={props.link_class}
                      target="_blank"
                      referrerPolicy="no-referrer"
                      rel="noopener"
                      href={item.startsWith("http") ? item : `http://${item}`}
                      onClick={function(evt: React.SyntheticEvent) {
                        evt.stopPropagation();
                      }}
                      style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                    >
                      {`${item}`}{" "}
                    </MUI_Link>
                  </span>
                );
              }

              if (hashtag_regex.exec(item)) {
                return (
                  <Link
                    href={`/hashtag_posts?hashtag_text=${item.slice(1)}`}
                    as={`/hashtags/${item.slice(1)}/posts`}
                    key={i}
                  >
                    <a style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                      <MUI_Link
                        className={props.link_class}
                        component="span"
                        onClick={function(evt: React.SyntheticEvent) {
                          evt.stopPropagation();
                          props.send_to_root("SHOW_PROGRESS");
                        }}
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                      >
                        {`${item}`}{" "}
                      </MUI_Link>
                    </a>
                  </Link>
                );
              }

              if (bold_regex.exec(item)) {
                return (
                  <span
                    key={i}
                    style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}
                  >
                    {`${item.split("**").join("")}`}{" "}
                  </span>
                );
              }

              return item + " ";
            })}
          </span>
        );
      })}
    </span>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ContentProcessedText);
```

I tried many ways but didn't get the expected results.

Comment: like here we use two stars for making text bold

Comment: why not splitting by `**` before splitting by words ? Then yo ucould tag the words that should be bold and split by space.

Comment: @R.LM i did that but when it comes to splitting by space doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I used the react-text-replace package and helped me to replace the string with a component as I wanted and it works with multiple regex rules and is easy to use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).